# PURGING objects on multiple instances of varnish

Tags: load-balancing, varnish, haproxy

I am using a Load Balancer (LB) in front of Varnish instances. Just say the LB is listening on Port: 80 and there are multiple instances of Varnish on different port nos.

i.e. I have a single LB which is connected to 4 instances of varnish, and LB is executing in a round-robin fashion.

Now, how can I purge objects on Varnish and maintain consistency among different instances of Varnish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to this is to use low TTLs for content you know you'll need to purge. With a 10 second TTL there is probably no need to send purges at all. Problem solved at the cost of some backend requests. Unless your backend is very slow, or your traffic levels are in the 100/1000s per second, this will work fine.

Another slighty dirty solution, given that your LB is in fact doing round-robin, is just to let the purging process send the PURGE request n times. One request for each Varnish behind it. This is of course a bit brittle, as you might (/will) forget to tune this when you add more servers.

If you really want it dirty you can do restarts in VCL and chain the processes. Let Varnish #1, after purging its own cache, use Varnish #2 as a backend for the PURGE requests. #2 does the same and passes it on to #3, rinse and repeat. Here be dragons, don't do this unless you're quite familiar with VCL.